# C# MVC controller method not being called when Html.TextBoxFor() has letter and digit characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I have a .cshtml file that has a TextBoxFor is like `Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchValue)`

the method in the controller that is accessed when the submit button is pressed is

`Search(string searchValue, string searchType)`

everything works fine if I put all digit characters in the textbox for example 111222233334444 I can hit a break point, however if I mix in letter characters like DDD222233334444 the method is not called, I won't hit the same breakpoint in the method.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help

Edit, add more code:
index.cshtml page

```
<div class="inputHolder">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchValue)
   </div>
.
.
.
<div id="actionHolder" class="actionHolder">
    <input type="image" source="~/Images/Submit.png" id="submitSearch" class="imageSubmit" />
</div>
```

and the controller method

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchValue, string searchType)
{
   Repository repo = new Repository(); <---- break point here works when all digits, but not if a mix of digit and letters or all letters
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in the dev console in the browser?

Comment: I cant find one

Comment: Please include the code, and indicate where the breakpoint is in that function.

Comment: original question updated

Comment: Was able to test on my end, and worked as expected :/

Comment: hmmm, thanks for taking a look...

Comment: Are you using any regular expression in your model? You can see it in SearchValue property in your model. And just checking are you sure you have SearchValue property in your model as string and not integer? Would have given you client-side error anyways.

Comment: Are there any attributes decorating your model.  @gutsy_guy brings up a good point, the models property for SearchValue may have an attribute that forces number types on the front end.

Comment: thanks for taking a look, ended up being an issue with a complicated JS IF statement